# Search Bar in Angular6/Firebase Not Showing Results

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs, angular6

this is my second time using StackOverflow. I'm currently learning Angular6, and I'm trying to integrate a search bar to query "clients" in firebase.

I have some basic CRUD operations working, but cannot seem to get the search bar working. Here are the relevant functions to the search bar.

```js
//client-search.component.ts
export class ClientSearchComponent implements OnInit {

 clients;
 startAt: BehaviorSubject<string|null> = new BehaviorSubject("");
 endAt: BehaviorSubject<string|null> = new BehaviorSubject("\uf8ff");

  constructor(private clientsSvc: ClientService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.clientsSvc.getClient(this.startAt, this.endAt).subscribe(clients =>           this.clients = clients);
  }

  search($event) {
    let q = $event.target.value;
    console.log("Our start: " + q);
    this.startAt.next(q);
    console.log(this.startAt.next(q));
    this.endAt.next(q + "\uf8ff");
  }
```

```html
<!-- client-search.component.html -->

   
<h1>Client Search</h1>

<input type="text" (keydown)="search($event)" placeholder="search clients..." class="input">


<div *ngFor="let client of clients">

  <h4>{{clients?.name}}</h4>

  <p>

<!-- {{movie?.Plot}} -->

  </p>

</div>


<div *ngIf="clients?.length < 1">

  <hr>

  <p>

    No results found :(

  </p>

</div>
```

Inside my client service, I have a function that queries firebase to return observables back to list them.

```js
getClient(start, end): FirebaseListObservable<any> {
    const r: any = this.firebase.list('/clients', ref =>
      ref.orderByChild('name').limitToFirst(10).startAt(start).endAt(end)
    );
    return r;
  }
```

#### Update

After digging deeper, ngOnInit is called getClient(), but it doesn't seem to like the parameters. Any way around this?

```
ClientsComponent.html:1 ERROR Error: Query: First argument passed to startAt(), endAt(), or equalTo() cannot be an object.
at Function.push../node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.cjs.js.Query.validateQueryEndpoints_ (index.cjs.js:4702)
at Query.push../node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.cjs.js.Query.startAt (index.cjs.js:4964)
at client.service.ts:55
at AngularFireDatabase.push../node_modules/angularfire2/database/database.js.AngularFireDatabase.list (database.js:18)
at ClientService.push../src/app/clients/shared/client.service.ts.ClientService.getClient (client.service.ts:54)
at ClientSearchComponent.push../src/app/clients/client-search/client-search.component.ts.ClientSearchComponent.ngOnInit (client-search.component.ts:23)
at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:8945)
at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:10209)
at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:10171)
at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:10804)
```

Comment: do you receive any error? have you checked that your firebase call starts and returns values with developer tools?

Comment: @firegloves I've gotten this looked over by a friend of mine as well. No errors on the console and also can't make much out of my limited experience in angular

Comment: @firegloves is there a way to display what's being returned from getClient()?

Comment: if you are using chrome you can press f12, then open network tab. there are listed all async calls. if you can see an entry for your search your call starts, if selecting it you can see a response it is also returning back a response to you

Comment: @firegloves it seems as if my function getClient() isn't being called when I try to call it during ngOnInit().

i updated the original post for you to take a look at the error

Comment: it sounds really strange...have you debugged to tell that it's not called? or have you puttend a console.log into getClient method and it doesn't print anything?

Comment: sorry @firegloves just updated the post. I simply put console.log() before and after my .getClient().subscribe() call in ngOnInit. The console.log() prior to the .getClient().subscribe() is being called, but then it doesn't like the arguments being passed in, and therefore getClient() isn't running.

I'm new to rxjs, and after following some tutorials, I don't know what changes I need to make. it's having issues with the variables startAt and endAt.

Comment: i don't know firebase but reading on web it seems that startAt() and endAt() receive a number. they act like slice(), so I can't figure out what you are trying to do. Can you explain me?

Comment: of course. I'm making a search bar that will live query firebase and return a list of names.

variables startAt and endAt should be the beginning and end of the string that I type in the search bar depending on the person I'm searching for.

Comment: It seems that you are mixing two syntax of startAt and endAt. I think you should use this one accordingly to yout needs https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#startAt

Comment: Let me know, please

Comment: sorry for the late reply, finally able to get back to looking at the code. will keep you posted.